# Custom template standard values (SXA): add a custom variant to a page content control

Tags: sxa

I created a custom template to use with the SXA carousel component. On the standard values > presentation > details, I selected the Page Content control and I want to use a custom variant (which is already created, published) with it but only the default options appear in the dropdown. Does anyone know how to add a custom variant?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways how you can use your own [Rendering Variant](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/create_a_rendering_variant) with Page Content rendering:

1. Put it under Page Content node and as variants for certain renderings are matched by rendering name. So rendering placed under Page Content will be assigned to Page Content rendering. Like this:

[image]

2. Put your rendering variant wherever you want in .../Tenant/Site/Presentation/Rendering Variants node and link certain variant to certain rendering. For example, here I'm assigning *Default* Title rendering variant to be used with Page Content:

[image]

3. Assign the whole set of variants from one rendering to another. Bellow, I'm assigning all Promo renderings variants to Page Content:

[image]

Comment: number 1 is the approach I took before I posted the question and the variant still doesn't appear in the dropdown.

Comment: I've rechecked this today and it's working fine.