# I need to add SXA Page Content component to standard values of template

Tags: sxa, templates

I created a custom template to use with the SXA Page Content component. On the standard values > presentation > details, I selected the Page Content control and I want to use a custom variant (which is already created, published) with it but only the default options appear in the dropdown. Does anyone know how to add a custom variant?

Note: when I try to add the same component in the page itself I find all variants in the dropdown So I think the issue happen when I try to add component to it the standard values.

Also I checked this Question and applied the steps thet mentioned ut still not working
[Custom template standard values (SXA): add a custom variant to a page content control](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/custom-template-standard-values-sxa-add-a-custom-variant-to-a-page-content-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use standard values on SXA page templates? You should use page designs...

It is logical that the variants are not found as your template does not live in a site (and your page does) and variants are defined per site.

But as mentioned, use page designs: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/page-designs.html

Check the best practices for SXA - with the recommendation not to use standard values to set presentation details here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/recommendations--structuring-pages.html#UUID-bb67a180-bf67-2c37-6b11-f7df38991c39_section-idm46212287364752_body

> All sites in a single Tenant use the same set of templates. Each of
> them can have separate style items or even use a different grid.
> Unless you are using a single shared site for the whole tenant as your
> styles' holder, this can result in broken layouts on some sites.
>
> As an alternative, use partial designs or snippets with sets of
> preconfigured renderings. Setting your presentation up in this way
> creates a balance of flexibility, and makes the experience more
> streamlined and manageable.
>
> If you have designs that you want to share between all sites within a
> tenant, consider creating shared site functionalitythat contains your
> page and partial designs so that you can reuse those.